# How to find the publish time of an update in CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

When I check updates in a CentOS 6.8, I can find some updates.

```
# yum list updates
......
Updated Packages  
bind.i686                        32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2               updates
bind-libs.i686                   32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2               updates
bind-utils.i686                  32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2               updates
```

I've tried downloading the RPM files with yumdownloader and listing their modification time.

```
# ll
total 5192
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4191788 Oct 21 17:16 bind-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2.i686.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  922948 Oct 21 17:16 bind-libs-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2.i686.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  190168 Oct 21 17:16 bind-utils-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2.i686.rpm
```

Is the modification time of the RPM file the publish time of the update? If not, how can I find it?
(By publish time, I mean the time when the update becomes available in the repository.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in a particular date of packages try this:

```
:~# yum install yum-plugin-changelog
```

and after that:

```
:~# yum changelog num package_name
```

Where the **num** determines the amount of data displayed and **package_name** is name of your package.

Full command:

```
:~# yum changelog 1 bind
```

This is the release date of the package. As for the date of publication, I think that it is hard to determine.

Comment: No problem, if really useful please vote (check arrow up on left side my answer).

Comment: But the time seems like a build time instead of a publish time. I updated the bind to bind-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.1.i686 on Oct 21, and the date of the newest bind-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2.i686 in the result of changelog is Oct 17. If it's publish time, the newest bind-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2.i686 should have been installed on Oct 21.

Comment: Excuse me, it seems that I don't have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: [rpm-packaging-guide.github.io](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/) states that the `changelog` is: _a list of datestamped entries for each Version-Release of the package. They log packaging changes, not software changes. Examples of packaging changes: adding a patch, changing the build procedure_

Comment: Fantastic command - great way to see if backported security updates are being made to a package.

Answer (score 0):

The actual release date cannot be extracted from RPM. You can get build and install time:

```
# rpm -qi glibc |grep Date
Install Date: Sat Sep  3 07:58:12 2016
Build Date  : Thu Aug 18 15:26:02 2016
```

But when the package become available has to be retrieved from other sources. Usually there is some tools. E.g. Fedora has Bodhi which release errata. RHEL release errata, which are downloadable from RHN or Satellite and have release date in it.